How to do the JSON Schema Validation in SOAPUI
I have tried many ways to do the JSON schema validation and wrote a custom function to do as well which works fine for simple responses but not for the nested responses. I wanted to use the simple way to do the JSON schema validation in SOAPUI and create schema using https://www.jsonschema.net/app/schemas/0 and then use a way to do the comparison of JSON response with JSON schema.
Followed below solution but seems like this doesn't work anymore as the solution was suggested 9 years back
How do I validate a JSON response against a Schema in SoapUI
Response I want to compare:
{
  "responseZones": [
    {
      "responseZone": "South EAST",
      "responseZoneCode": "SSE",
      "region": {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Southern Metro",
        "code": "SOM",
        "division": {
          "id": 1,
          "code": "SD1",
          "headquarters": "PPP",
          "psa": {
            "id": "0",
            "name": "Port ABC",
            "code": "ABC",
            "unitCode": "ABC",
            "headquarters": "St ABC"
          }
        }
      },
      "units": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "type": "CIU",
          "name": "Port Ten",
          "code": "SUPTEF"
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "type": "45NTN",
          "name": "TTGSD"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

